# Windows phone browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone

I'm making a mobile version for my site, and I was wondering if Windows phones use IE as their browser? If so, does it support CSS3? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser on WP7 phones is indeed based on IE.  They support basic CSS3 features, but certainly not all of them.  You'll have to consult feature support charts, which are easy to find by Googling (eg, [this one](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html)).

Anecdotally, the "Mango" release phones seem to be running essentially IE7 (based on the fact that I could reproduce WP7 issues by looking at the page in IE7).  Supposedly though, the newer ones are based on IE9.

Ultimately, it's best to be fairly conservative when writing web pages for mobile.  There are lots of legacy phones out there, which will crap out if if your site uses all the bleeding edge techniques.  And remember, even if a phone technically supports a feature like animation, it may not necessarily be a great experience if it's an older phone.